# Run autotests as a result of clicking 'merge pull request' button

Tags: git, github, webhooks

Is there any way to set up github web hooks in the way merge happens only in the case autotests passed on merged version?

I.e

1. I receive pull requiest and review it
2. use 'merge pull requiest' button
3. merge details are sent to my server
4. local merged version created locally
5. autotests run
6. autotests result is sent back to github
7. merge or not depending on result

Possible solution:
1) set up post-receive hook
2) run tests
3) roll back commit if tests failed using Github API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tool that continually checks and potentially merges GitHub pull requests. Developers can communicate with the tool through comments on the pull requests.

https://github.com/xen-org/pull-request-manager

Answer (score 1):

There is not, you'd have to set that up yourself.